# JcrExportCommand filter to exclude "mgnl:page" in magnolia cms

Tags: magnolia

I would like filter out "mgnl:page" nodes for the JcrExportCommand in magnolia when I execute it on a node with a custom action.

The filter I wrote in the code below doesn't work. It still gives me mgnl:page children nodes in the exported file.

```
//set filter to only export mgnl:area subnodes
    DefaultFilter filter = new JcrExportCommand.DefaultFilter();
    NodeFilteringPredicate nodePredicate = new NodeFilteringPredicate();
    nodePredicate.setNodeTypes(Lists.newArrayList("mgnl:area"));
    filter.setNodePredicate(nodePredicate);
```

How do I set the correct filter to export everything but "mgnl:page" subnodes? I believed that setting the NodeFilteringPredicate to "mgnl:area" I get only nodes that are of that type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the filter on `JcrExportCommand` for it to take effect:

```
DefaultFilter filter = new DefaultFilter();
filter.getNodePredicate().getNodeTypes().add("mgnl:page");
jcrExport.setFilter(Collections.singletonMap("website", filter));
```

Comment: Thanks @michid  I tested it and it works but since the top level node is of type mgnl:page it removes it and everything below it from the exported file :) I would like to create a filter that would keep the top level page node and remove all children of type mgnl:page in the exported file. Can I achieve that with a filter?

Comment: In this case you probably have to implement your own predicate to decide which nodes to keep. Inherit from `AbstractPredicate` and implement your logic there and set your predicate in the default filter by calling `JcrExportCommand.DefaultFilter#setNodePredicate()`.

Comment: Nothing I knew of. I suggest you start by deriving your predicate from [NodeFilteringPredicate](https://git.magnolia-cms.com/projects/PLATFORM/repos/main.pub/browse/magnolia-core/src/main/java/info/magnolia/jcr/predicate/NodeFilteringPredicate.java#45) and override the [evaluate()](https://git.magnolia-cms.com/projects/PLATFORM/repos/main.pub/browse/magnolia-core/src/main/java/info/magnolia/jcr/predicate/AbstractPredicate.java#46) method. Here you have to decide whether the passed node is a page and whether it is top level or not. You can probably do that by looking at its parents.

Answer (score 1):

*** this is not the answer to my question but instead the answer to a comment since code is not properly formated in a comment ***

As @michid suggested I created a custom Predicator and used JcrExportCommand.DefaultFilter#setNodePredicate()to apply it.

I am expecting to get an exported YAML with filtered nodes according to the Predicate but instead I am still getting all the nodes (including children of type mgnl:page).

My custom Predicate class is:

```
public class MyPredicate extends NodeFilteringPredicate {

    public boolean evaluate(Node node) throws AccessDeniedException, ItemNotFoundException, RepositoryException {
            //only nodes that are not of type mgnl:page 
            if((node.getParent().getPrimaryNodeType().getName().contains("mgnl:page"))&&(node.getPrimaryNodeType().getName().contains("mgnl:page"))) {
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            }
    }
}
```

My custom Action class is:

```
public class MyAction extends AbstractMultiItemAction<UzhVersioning>  {


private AbstractPredicate<Node> MyPredicate;



public MyAction(xxxVersioning definition, JcrItemAdapter item, UiContext uiContext) {
    super(definition, item, uiContext);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}




@Override
public void execute() {

    //export nodes from a JCR workspace
    JcrExportCommand exporter = new JcrExportCommand();
    //sets export format to yaml
    exporter.setFormat("yaml");
    exporter.setRepository("website");


    //set filter to only export top mgnl:page and its mgnl:area nodes
    DefaultFilter filter = new JcrExportCommand.DefaultFilter();
    AbstractPredicate<Node> predicate = new MyPredicate();
    filter.setNodePredicate(predicate);
    exporter.setFilters(Collections.singletonMap("website", filter));



    //setup the root directory for exports
    File rootDir = new File("/Users/asusti/Downloads/yamlExport");
    // clean up first
    rootDir.delete();
    rootDir.mkdirs();

    //get root node
    Node node = (Node) getItems().get(0).getJcrItem();


    try {
        //set export path
        exporter.setPath(node.getPath());
        File file = new File(rootDir, node.getName()+".yaml");
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        exporter.setOutputStream(out);
        exporter.execute(MgnlContext.getInstance());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```